# Why is this summation formula wrong?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction, summation

This is the alternate form of the summation formula:
$$
\sum^{n}_{k=0} a(c)^k =  \frac{ac^{n+1} - a}{c - 1}
$$

so why is this wrong?
$$
\sum^{n}_{k=0} (-\frac{1}{2})^k =  \frac{(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1} - 1}{(-\frac{1}{2}) - 1}
$$

Comment: The numerator up top should be $a c^{n+1}-a$.

Comment: @RonGordon fixed, but still the second summation doesn't match.

Comment: I do not understand you problem - it all looks OK to me.  Do a check on for small $n$ - it works.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? It looks right to me.

Comment: It's correct. Why do you think it's not?

Comment: @Ted check on your calculator

Comment: As has been mentioned repeatedly, your formula is correct. However, it is considered unfashionable to have negative numbers in the denominator. And for calculation,  the many minus signs increase the risk of error.

Comment: Certainly this formula is correct but it might need some simplification if you want.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is correct for $c\ne 1$.

Fraction in RHS has no sense, when $c=1$ $\Bigl($undefined value like $\dfrac{0}{0}$$\Bigr)$.